# How to reflect field names and types

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

```
struct Vec3 {
  x:float;
  y:float;
  z:float;
}
table Monster {
  pos:Vec3; // Struct.
  mana:short = 150;
  hp:short = 100;
  name:string;
  friendly:bool = false (deprecated);
  inventory:[ubyte];  // Vector of scalars.
  color:Color = Blue; // Enum.
  weapons:[Weapon];   // Vector of tables.
  equipped:Equipment; // Union.
  path:[Vec3];        // Vector of structs.
}
```

1.Compile this flatbuffers schema to C++ source.

2.How to reflect Monster(C++ struct) and get members and types?

Comment: Why do you need this reflection? What is the underlying problem you need to solve? And what makes you believe that such reflection is the only (or best) solution to that problem? Please always ask about the actual problem you have, and tell us about what research you have done to solve the problem, and what solution you want to try (or better yet already have tried).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  We are using protobuf send and analysis(using refletion) data now.And we found that flatbuffers parse faster.So I'm trying flatbuffers reflection for like csv file parse.

Answer (score 0):

C++ FlatBuffers comes with two reflection systems, the full binary schema file based reflection, and mini reflection. I recommend the latter, as it is simpler and more efficient. Details on both here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html

However, a system like FlatBuffers was designed for use without reflection. Most uses of reflection are misguided ("I want to write general code that can handle all my serialization"), and you are best of not using it at all.